# What keyboard shortcut is appropriate in a web application to move the focus to the page menu button

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard, wai-aria

I want to support users for my website who have intrinsic difficulty with using a mouse.  This includes people who have visual or motor deficiencies.

Instead of maintaining a 1980s style menu bar which takes up the top of every page I have moved that information into a drop-down menu which is activated by selecting a page menu button which has the common appearance of a hamburger.  As you know the hamburger icon was designed by Norm Cox for the Xerox Star, the world's first graphical user interface.  I have searched through long lists of common keyboard shortcuts but I cannot find any that are recommended for use in selecting such a button in a web application.  Note that this is not the **browser's** hamburger button in the browser toolbar, it is one that is part of the displayed web page.

```
    <button id="menuButton" class="left"
        title="Main Page Menu" aria-hidden="true"
        aria-haspopup="menu"
        aria-label="Open the menu" aria-expanded="false">
      <div class="menuicon"></div>
      <div class="menuicon"></div>
      <div class="menuicon"></div>
    </button>
```

where the CSS for menuicon is:

```
div.menuicon {
            width: 35px;
            height: 5px;
            background-color: black;
            margin: 6px 0;
            border-radius: 2.5px;
            }
```

To see what this looks like try https://www.jamescobban.net/FamilyTree/nominalIndex.php.

The only way I can see for a person who cannot use a mouse to get to this button is to [Shift-]tab from the element of the form which has the initial focus until reaching the page menu button.  This seems unnecessarily cumbersome.  Obviously I have to avoid those keyboard shortcuts that have a standard meaning.  For example I cannot use Home, or Alt-Home.  But it should ideally be a keyboard shortcut that my customers already know because it is used by other tools.

Comment: I notice that on the linked page the `aria-expanded` never changes. Maybe it’s still work in progress?

Comment: Thank you.  The EcmaScript invoked by clicking on the button includes "    element.ariaExpanded        = true;
    element.ariaLabel           = document.getElementById('closeTheMenu').innerText;"

Comment: When I inspect the DOM properties of the button ariaExpanded changes appropriately.

Comment: I checked again in Firefox, it doesn’t change. Maybe a compatibility issue?

Comment: The value in inspector doesn't change, probably because that reflects the HTML.  Also the aria-label doesn't change in the inspector view.  When I look at the DOM properties I see it change: <button id="menuButton" class="left" title="Main Page Menu" aria-hidden="true" aria-haspopup="menu" aria-label="Open the menu" aria-expanded="false">
accessKey: ""
accessKeyLabel: ""
ariaExpanded: true
ariaLabel: "Close the menu"

Comment: Oh I see now that `ariaExpanded` is not supported by Firefox, as it doesn’t seem to implement the ARIAmixin interface. `setAttribute('aria-expanded')` would work. Why are you hiding the button from assistive technology via `aria-hidden`?

Comment: I am using Firefox 109.0 and I see the value of aria-expanded change in the DOM properties display when I assign a value to element.ariaExpanded so ARIAMixin seems to be implemented.  As I am just starting to add ARIA support I simply copied an example.  I have removed aria-hidden.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Attributes/aria-expanded shows aria-hidden set for the graphic of a button.  Is that to stop the browser from announcing the textual contents of the button?  Why would it do that when it has an aria-label setting?

Comment: Concerning `aria-hidden`, that’s a good question. The most common pattern is to hide an icon when there is real text next to it, like in a Text+icon button. In the example, all contents are overwritten (for AT) by means of `aria-labelledby`, so hiding the icon does probably nothing additional.

Comment: For `aria-expanded`, I just tested again in Firefox 109 to be sure, and it’s still not reflecting the state. Especially not in the accessibility properties.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to improve those users’ experience, I’d recommend to not hide the main menu items in the first place.

> Discoverability is cut almost in half by hiding a website’s main navigation. Also, task time is longer and perceived task difficulty increases.

[Nielsen Norman Group, 2016](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/hamburger-menus/)

This would give you an opportunity to render the menu items larger as well, which improves usability with motor impairments.

### Shortcuts

The [ARIA standard has a long section on keyboard shortcuts](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/practices/keyboard-interface/#x6-9-keyboard-shortcuts).

In HTML, [the `accesskey` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey) allows to define a single letter, and leave handling the modifier keys to the browser and the operating system.

```html
<button aria-label="Menu" accesskey="m">
<!-- OR -->
…
<a href="/" accesskey="h"><u>H</u>ome</a>
```

This is great in theory, but in practice [there are some concerns](https://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/accesskey#spec).

I still would go with this, as it’s the best option we currently have. You wouldn’t want to handle platform conventions in your code.

You can even retrieve the key combination the browser finally assigned by using the [`accessKeyLabel` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/accessKeyLabel), but browser support is not great.

```js
button.title += ` [${button.accessKeyLabel || button.accessKey}]`;
```

If you are using single character shortcuts, you need to provide a mechanism to change these shortcuts, should they interfere with other AT shortcuts:

[Understanding Success Criterion 2.1.4: Character Key Shortcuts](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/character-key-shortcuts.html)

### Render menu items big enough

When visiting the linked page, I notice that the actual menu items are only 17px high and barely have space in between them.

Having large enough click and touch targets is especially important for users with motor impairments.

If you’d like to optimise particularly for that group of users, you should respect [WCAG AAA Criterium 2.5.5 Target size](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/target-size) demands, targets should be **at least 44×44 px**. You will find almost the same recommendation in [Android’s Guidelines](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7101858?hl=en) and in [Apple’s Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/accessibility#buttons-and-controls).

If not, **at least 24×24 px** would be appropriate, as is required by the upcoming WCAG 2.2 in [AA Criterium 2.5.8 Target size (minimum)](https://www.w3.org/TR/svg-aam-1.0/#include_elements)

Comment: Note that WCAG 2.5.5 is a AAA guideline which is currently not required by most countries' accessibility laws. Not that that means you shouldn't try to achieve it. When WCAG 2.2 comes out, there will be a AA guideline (2.5.8) that targets should be at least 24x24. Making 2.5.8 a AA guideline means that it will most likely be required by most countries when they update their accessibility laws to WCAG 2.2.

Comment: Thank you for your careful consideration of my page.  I am relatively new to ARIA.  I assumed that anyone with a visual or motor deficiency will have set the defaults for zoom or character size to ensure that

Comment: I cannot see how any significant website can afford the real-estate on every page to display all of the items in the menu at 44px.  After all the menu is only a navigation support, not the service being delivered.  At your suggestion I have changed the style of the menu items to     a.menuitem { 
                ...
                font-size:          150%;
                ...
                text-decoration:    none;
                padding-top:        3px;
                padding-bottom:     3px;
                }